# Android Studio launches multiple GitHub instances

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I recently installed GitHub on my laptop and set it up with Android Studio but I'm having this issue and can't figure out what's going on.

Basically, every time I launch Android Studio it automatically triggers 10 to 30 or more instances of GitHub.  [see image at the bottom]

I don't know if this is related but I also get an error message in Android Studio:

- *Unable to run git: C:\Users\ [blahblah] \GitHub.exe (Empty git --version output: )*

I also noticed the same thing happens whenever I run an app in the emulator (after closing all GitHub windows previously launched) but this time the "git --version" error doesn't pop up anymore.

I'm new to git so I'm not very familiar yet of how all this works..

I installed GitHub and Updated Android Studio a couple of days ago, so everything is up to date.

I did some research online but didn't find anything useful thus far..

Any ideas? :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need to run "GitHub.exe"

"Unable to run git: C:\Users\ [blahblah] \GitHub.exe (Empty git --version output: )"

---you need to run "git"

ex:  "C:\Users\ [blahblah] \git.exe"

ex2: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe"

2) "Empty git --version output:" means that Android Studio could not find "git.exe" in the given directory.

3) Here are two great tutorials that worked for me:

***setting up Android Studio:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBD4xhH5vIE&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSPjWpLPFEfOCbezi6vATIh

***setting up Git:

http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/04/git-video-tutorial/